# Populate f.hidden_field with f.select value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am looking at how to populate a hidden_field with the value of a f.select field however I am having difficulty. I was going to use javascript but the html created from my haml makes it difficult to assign an id to the select I wish to pass the value from.

```
= f.select :trial, [['Yes', 'true'], ['No', 'false']], {}, :id => "free-trial", class: 'selectpicker mandatory'
```

This generates the following html

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <select class="selectpicker mandatory" id="free-trial" name="campaign[trial]" style="display: none;">
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false" selected="selected">No</option>
  </select>
  <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select mandatory">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="free-trial" data-original-title="" title="">
      <span class="filter-option pull-left">No</span>&nbsp;
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="max-height: 133px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;">
      <li rel="0">
        <a tabindex="0" class=""> 
          <span class="text">
            Yes
          </span>
          <i class="icon-ok check-mark"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li rel="1" class="selected">
        <a tabindex="0" class="">
          <span class="text">No</span>
          <i class="icon-ok check-mark"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This html when display is actually two selects one hidden with the ID assigned and a second which is displayed without the id associated. As a result my clicking on the visible select means the associated jquery doesnt fire.

Comment: Show, what you expect, if you want help.

Comment: I don't understand. You say it's difficult to assign an id to the select, but your select already has an id of 'free-trial'

Comment: @luissimo I just updated the question there in response to your question. The last paragraph details this.

Comment: @Bartek Gładys I think the first line details what I expect i.e. to be able to popualte a hidden field with the value of a select field.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you properly, you want catch value from select to hidden_input. You can use jquery to do that:

```
$('#free-trial').on('change', function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('#your_hidden_input').attr('value', val);
}
```

Comment: As i said in the question there are two selects being created by the haml. One is hidden which has the id attributed to it and other is visible which does not have the id attribute. I therefore cannot use the #free-trial as an identifier as I am not able to click on the hidden select but rather the visible select which does not have the #free-trial identifier.